# How to dynamically change the height & width of view in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, autolayout

I am developing an app in iOS.I have used autolayout ,constraints to build the UI.But still i am very much confused about it.I am not able to create accurate UI using autolaout & size classes.Please pardon me if i am asking very basic question because i am very fresh to iOS.

Here I have created a Login screen.In which i have a container in middile which contains some text filed & image at top which is kind of app logo and below the container i have two buttons.I have three problems.

1. Container is not aligned properly.It size keep on increasing & margin between container & text fields is increasing.So UI looks bad.I want to increase width & height in equal proportion so that it does not look bad.

2.The size of logo should be increase in equal proportion.It's height & width.

3.Buttons at bottom their height is fixed.Their height should increase in equal proportion.

**ScreenShot**
[image: screenshot]

Comment: The key thing is having a clear layout requirement.  That is the best way of determining the constraints. Your desired layout is somewhat vague. From what you said, the simplest option to start with is to use constraints which allow flexibility on the items which need to grow. e.g. For the image you could center it horizontally, set its width to be <= (a max size), set its aspect to be 1:1, set the top to be >= (minimum margin) and its leading to be >= (minimum margin). That will allow the image to scale up to a maximum but not break any margins. Use precise constraints to tie things together.

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel well thanks.I am very much fresher to these things so can you suggest me some of the complete tutorials where i can find the solution.

Comment: Start with the Apple docs so you understand how it all works: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html. Then I would jump in and use writing your app as your tutorial.

Comment: Ok I will figure out.Thanks @RoryMcKinnel

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel i have studied the link you mentioned.But it does not have each constraints explained.

Comment: Try this tutorial and the second in the series. http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2

Comment: i have already studied this tutorial.Issue is that they are only target one device for landscape & portrait mode.They have not done it for multiple screen size devices so that is why i am asking this question. @RoryMcKinnel

Comment: All I can suggest is you update your question with a precise definition of how you want all the items to look individually and relative to each other for different screen sizes. It will then be easier to help. Beyond simple relative layout, for more complex sizing you will probably need to write code that manipulates the constraints via IBOutlets.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you want keep proportion you need to work with aspect ratio constraints as such:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint =[NSLayoutConstraint
                           constraintWithItem:view
                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                           toItem:childView
                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                           multiplier:4.0/3.0 //Aspect ratio: 4*height = 3*width
                           constant:0.0f];
[view addConstraint:constraint];
```

One more thing you need to know is not to limit the view grow with other constraint.

Lets say you want the top image to grow don't add some fix leading or trailing from the side, just add top constraint and center the view to its superview.

If you want to limit the image size so it want get out of superview bounds just add a constraint leading and trailing with gratherOrEquelTo relation

Hope I was clear.

//Edit

If you want some minimum size for height or width just add a constraint of height or with the minimum size you want with the relation of gratherOrEquelTo